# Adding Object to PHP array

Tags: php

I'm trying to add an object while I'm declaring an array in PHP but I can't figure out the right syntax.  Here's what i'm trying:

```
 $obr = [
    ["Office", "Orders", { role: "style" } ],       
    ["Jacksonville", 1254, "magenta"],
    ["Orlando", 653, "blue"],
    ["Sarasota", 789, "green"],
    ["Stuart", 468, "yellow"],
    ["Tampa", 982, "cyan"]
];
```

Comment: That's not an object.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{ role: "style" }` with `(object)[role => "style"]`.  This will cast an associative array to stdClass

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an array, if you want to add another array inside the first one, try something like this:

```
$obj = array(
  array("Office", "Orders", array("role" => "style")),       
  array("Jacksonville", 1254, "magenta"),
  array("Orlando", 653, "blue"),
  array("Sarasota", 789, "green"),
  array("Stuart", 468, "yellow"),
  array("Tampa", 982, "cyan"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've posted JSON notation of an object (JavaScript).

PHP language uses another syntax:

```
$obj = array(
     array("Office", "Orders", array("role" => "style")),       
     array("Jacksonville", 1254, "magenta"),
     // ...
);
```

or (I prefer this one as more flexible)

```
$obj = array();
$obj[] = array("Office", "Orders", array("role" => "style"));
$obj[] = array("Jacksonville", 1254, "magenta");
// ...
```

(When array is defined, you can use `print_r($obj);` to dump it and see its total structure.)